# Magento resource model filter and limit

Tags: php, orm, magento, paging

Hi when getting a resource model in magent using  Mage::getResourceModel  i can add filters no problem but how can i limit the result set to say 5 or 10?

Comment: Your question isn't 100% clear.  You say you're "getting a resource model", but your question implies that you're getting a collection (which is, confusingly, a type of resource model).  Including the code you're using is always a good idea, especially with Magento questions.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you're talking about Magento Collections, the ORM uses a paging style interface to limit things.   You tell the collection how big you want each page to be (`setPageSize`), then you tell it which page you want to be on (`setCurPage`).

```
//same as, and "better" than Mage:getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->setPageSize(10)->setCurPage(1);     //first 10 items


Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->setPageSize(10)->setCurPage(2);     //second 10 items

///etc...
```

Comment: How would one add a join to this collection? When I try to add ->join after the getCollection, Magento barks that it's an undefined method.

Comment: @Corgaloe The collection object has no join method, and Magento's collection API doesn't have built in joining (except for the EAV collection types, but they automatically join/query for EAVs).  You need to modify the collection's select statment.  Try ...->getCollection()->getSelect()->join.... -- the select object is a Zend 1.x select object,

Comment: the join you suggested works, but then the paging gets dropped from the resulting sql statement. I had to get the collection, then use joinField on it, then use getSelect()->limitPage(1,10) in order to get a product collection with a joined table and paging all together.

Comment: @Corgalore Right -- when you access the SQL statement directly you're breaking the abstraction, and all sorts of weird things can/will happen.

Answer (score 3):

```
$select->limit(5)
```

check for example the `_getProducts()` method in `app/core/mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Url.php` (line 806)

Comment: no that doesnt work when using it with mage::getResourceModel